# How to use extended glob with parentheses in a command passed to `bash -c`?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I am trying to use an extended glob with `bash -c`, but haven't found a way to get it working.

### Things I've tried

1. `bash -c 'for f in *.!(ext); do echo $f; done'`

   Result:

   ```
   bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
   ```
2. `bash -c 'for f in *.!\(ext\); do echo $f; done'`

   Result:

   ```
   *.!(ext)
   ```
3. `bash -c 'for f in *.!$0; do echo $f; done' '(ext)'`

   Result:

   ```
   *.!(ext)
   ```
4. `bash -c 'for f in "*.!(ext)"; do echo $f; done'`

   Result:

   ```
   *.!(ext)
   ```

Comment: `bash -O extglob -c 'echo *.!(ext)'`

Comment: `bash -O nullglob -O extglob -c 'echo !(*.ext)'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use an extended globbing pattern in `bash`, you will have to enable the `extglob` shell option in one way or another.

The easiest way to do this for an in-line `bash -c` script is to set the shell option with the `-O` option on the command line:

```
bash -O extglob -c 'script code here'
```

You could also just call `shopt -s extglob` *within the script*, but you have to make sure that this is done on a separate line as it changes the way the shell parses the code (it modifies the shell's syntax):

```
bash -c 'shopt -s extglob
         script code here'
```

As for your actual task of printing all names that don't end with the string `.ext`:

```
bash -O extglob -O dotglob -O nullglob -c 'printf "%s\n" !(*.ext)'
```

By additionally setting the `dotglob` and `nullglob` options the script would match hidden names, and would print a single empty line if there are no matches (rather than printing the unexpanded pattern).

Note that your pattern `*.!(ext)` would exclude filenames that end in `ext` (not just `.ext`) *and* filenames that do not contain a dot.

Comment: I found this answer because I was trying to do `shopt -s extglob && mv !(*.ext) dst/`, and the note that they need to be on separate lines saved me.